# Why does the last string not properly enter a multidemsional array which shows character frequency?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, anagram

I have been trying to find a solution for a long time but it seems like i cant.

I was trying to make a program that reads sentences from a file, puts the sentences as strings it into multidimensional array and quicksorts the array sentences alphabetically. Then it puts that array into an another array which shows the frequency of letters in a column position which shows the letter and frequency.

For example sentence 7 "CUD" would be row 7 and have a 1,1 and 1 in columns 3(c) 4(d) and 21(U). This works perfectly except for the last sentence which for some reason doesn't enter at all and shows random numbers.

```
void isAnAnagram(char anagramTester[][MAX_CHAR]) {
int countLetters[MAX_LINES][26] = {0};
int x;
for (int i =1; i <=MAX_LINES; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; (anagramTester[i][j] != '\0'); j++) {
        if (anagramTester[i][j] >= 'a' && anagramTester[i][j] <= 'z') {
            x = anagramTester[i][j] - 'a' +1;
            countLetters[i][x]++;
        } else if (anagramTester[i][j] >= 'A' && anagramTester[i][j] <= 'Z') {
            x = anagramTester[i][j] - 'A' +1;
            countLetters[i][x]++;
        }
    }
}
for(int i=1;i<=MAX_LINES;i++){ //Rows
    printf("row:%d ", i);
    for(int j=1;j<=26;j++){ //Cols

        printf("%d ",countLetters[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}}
```

This is the function which accepts a 2 dimensional array with strings in it
I have tried changing the loops but fundamentally I don't know why this error is only occurring in the last sentence.

here is the file input and output function

```
    void readSentences(char inputSentences[][MAX_CHAR]){
int lineNum = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("YOurDETAILS/input.txt", "r+");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
if(fp== NULL ){
    /* check does weather file exist etc*/
    perror("Error opening file");
    lineNum = -1;
    /* use this as a file not found code */
}
else {
    // fgets returns NULL when it gets to the end of the file
    for(lineNum = 1; lineNum <= MAX_LINES; lineNum++){
        if(fgets(inputSentences[lineNum], MAX_CHAR, fp) != NULL){
            inputSentences[lineNum][MAX_CHAR] = '\0';
        }
        else {
            inputSentences[lineNum][MAX_CHAR] = '\0';

            fclose(fp);
        }
        inputSentences[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHAR] = '\0';
    }


    }
    }

  void writeAnswer(char output[][MAX_CHAR]){
    FILE *fp = fopen("YOurDETAILS/output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp,"Sorted Array:\n");
    for (int i =1; i <= MAX_LINES; i++) {
       fprintf(fp,"sentence %d:%s \n ", i, output[i]);
     }
  fclose(fp);
   }
```

the contents of the input.txt file are

```
cat
O, Draconian devil! Oh, lame saint!
tac
Tom Marvolo Riddle
Software engineering
Leonardo da Vinci! The Mona Lisa!
Computer science
CUD
Act
cuddle
Hey there!
Old Immortal dovers
I am Lord Voldemort
duck
```

the sorting file is

```
void swap(char sentencesToSwap[][MAX_CHAR], int i, int j){
    for(int x = 0;x < MAX_CHAR; x++ ) {
        char temp = sentencesToSwap[i][x];
        sentencesToSwap[i][x] = sentencesToSwap[j][x];
        sentencesToSwap[j][x] = temp;
    }
}
void quicksort(char sentencesToSort[][MAX_CHAR], int first, int last){
    if(first < last){
        char pivotindex = partition(sentencesToSort, first, last);
        quicksort(sentencesToSort, first, pivotindex-1);
        quicksort(sentencesToSort, pivotindex+1, last);
    }
}
int partition(char sentencesToSort[][MAX_CHAR], int first, int last){
    swap(sentencesToSort, first, (first + last) / 2);
    char *pivot;
    pivot = sentencesToSort[first];      // remember pivot

    int index1 = first + 1; // index of first unknown value
    int index2 = last;    // index of last unknown value
    while (index1 <= index2) { // while some values still unknown
        if (strcasecmp(sentencesToSort[index1],pivot) <= 0)
            index1++;
        else if (strcasecmp(sentencesToSort[index2],pivot) > 0)
            index2--;
        else {
            swap(sentencesToSort, index1, index2);
            index1++;
            index2--;
        }
    }
    swap(sentencesToSort, first, index2); // put the pivot value between the two
    // sublists and return its index
    return index2;
}
```

The main file is below

```
   char sentences[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHAR];
    readSentences(sentences);
    isAnAnagram(sentences);
    quicksort(sentences, 0, MAX_LINES );
    writeAnswer(sentences);
```

Comment: Array indexing is zero-based in C.

Comment: Start with replacing those `a +1` and `int i = 1` with zeroes. Sometimes you get it right and sometimes you start with 0, that should raise your suspicion.

Comment: `for(lineNum = 1; lineNum <= MAX_LINES; lineNum++)` should be `lineNum = 0; lineNum < MAX_LINES;`

Comment: regarding: `FILE *fp = fopen("YOurDETAILS/input.txt", "r+");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
if(fp== NULL ){`   The function: `fseek()` changes the value in `errno` AND the call to `fopen()` sets the file position pointer to the beginning of the file.  Overall, this means the statement: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);` has no effect and should be removed

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  please consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `inputSentences[MAX_LINES][MAX_CHAR] = '\0';`  This indexes beyond the end of the array: `inputSentences[]`.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  In C, the valid indexes into an array are 0...[number of entries in array -1]

Comment: regarding: `for(int x = 0;x < MAX_CHAR; x++ ) {
        char temp = sentencesToSwap[i][x];
        sentencesToSwap[i][x] = sentencesToSwap[j][x];
        sentencesToSwap[j][x] = temp;
    }`   This is a very SLOW way to swap a sentence.  Suggest: `char temp[MAX_CHAR];  strcpy( temp, sentencesToSwap[i] );  strcpy( sentencesToSwap[i], sentencesToSwap[j] );  strcpy( sentencesToSwap[j], temp );`

Comment: Since the call to `fopen()` failed, this `if()` code block should end with `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  as there is no open file for the other code to process.

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE *fp = fopen("YOurDETAILS/output.txt", "w");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.